# Unicode point for Alef with a cap above?

Tags: arabic, unicode

How can the first letter of this word be represented in Unicode?

[image: Arabic word]

What is this sign called?

Answer (score 8):

> آ

[U-0622](https://codepoints.net/U+0622). It is called Alef with madda.

Comment: Please do not post single-line answers. The minimum character limit exists to enforce this very purpose. Instead, explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations and credible references. If, however, the question is *so* trivial that 5 words would completely answer it, this means the question is bad for the Stack Exchange format and should be closed.

Comment: خير الكلام ما قل ودل

Comment: Thanks! I was expecting a more tilde-like shape and wasn't sure it was a madda.

Comment: It is not exactly an elegant font, but there is nothing else it could be.

Comment: I think it's a perfect answer. It goes straight to the point.